# Is it possible to Create Testcases and Test Run Automatically on Testrail using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, continuous-integration, testrail

I have been able to integrate my Selenium and Testrail . I can pass testresults to the specified Testrun I have created manually on test rail.

I have a challenge and I want to know if this is possible currently.

I do not want to manually create the test cases  I have on selenium on test rail and I also do not want to have to create a new test run when I run my automation scripts .

I want to automatically check If the test case I'm running is not on test rail, selenium should add it automatically. Also I do not want to specify the TEST_RUN_ID . I want immediately I trigger or run a test cases it should create a test run by itself on Tesrrail. I need this because I'm implementing a CI/CD approach and I do not want any manual intervention . Please let me know if possible

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at our product called [Railflow](https://railflow.io), which provides very flexible integration of various testing platforms with TestRail.
It also has convenient integration with TestNG and Selenium, please see more details in our docs: https://docs.railflow.io/docs/testing-frameworks/testng

Please feel free to register for free 14-day evaluation:
https://railflow.io/register

Disclaimer: I'm developer of Railflow